# Openiddict OAuth2 redirect_uri response

Tags: c#, asp.net, openiddict

can you a bit help me to understand oauth flow.

When I make a request from Client app for authorize_code it redirect me to my endpoint like:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Auth(string code)
{
    var token = GetToken(code);

    return ""; //What should I return here? What server is expecting from me?

}
```

So the question maybe simple, what should I return from my redirect_uri?